# JavaScript Backspace Keycode doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, keycode, jquery-events

The Keycode for the Backspace just doesn't work I tried it in IE and Google Chrome and it doesn't display anything neither in the console nor the alert Code:

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
  if (e.which == 13) {
    window.alert("enter");
  } else if (e.which == 8) {
    window.alert("backspace");
  } else {
    $("#prompt").append(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The backspace doesn't trigger `keypress` in all browsers, use `keyup` instead.

Comment: and how can I handle that/could you please add an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyPress` event is invoked only for character (printable) keys, `keyDown` event is raised for all including nonprintable

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
  if (e.which == 13) {
    window.alert("enter");
  } else if (e.which == 8) {
    window.alert("backspace");
  } else {
    $("#prompt").append(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[References](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)

Comment: @STAT1C Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `keyup` instead of `keypress` event, as certain keys (such as backspace) will not cause that event to fire.

```js
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
  if (e.which == 13) {
    window.alert("enter");
  } else if (e.which == 8) {
    window.alert("backspace");
  } else {
    $("#prompt").append(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The keypress event is only evoked on printable keys. To print any key, you'll want to use the onkeydown event. It's raised for all including nonprintable such as Control, Shift, Alt, BackSpace, etc. Read more about they onkeydown event here: https://api.jquery.com/keydown/
Here's an example of how it would turn out:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` instead of `keypress` to get all the key codes

```js
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
  if (e.which == 13) {
    window.alert("enter");
  } else if (e.which == 8) {
    window.alert("backspace");
  } else {
    $("#prompt").append(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```